# Trailing dot after section number, table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

There is a trailing dot after the section number in the `beamer` table of contents, section entry. How can I get rid of it?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

\title{Presentation}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\part{Introduction}
\frame{\partpage}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{General}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection{Less General}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\section{Specific}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection{More Specific}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the `section in toc` template like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  \leavevmode%
  % prevents the period to be printed with the first/last section option
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>\beamer@toclastsection
  \else
  \ifnum\beamer@tempcount>0
    \inserttocsectionnumber\space
  \fi\fi%
  \inserttocsection\par%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]

\title{Presentation}
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\part{Introduction}
\frame{\partpage}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Table of Contents}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{General}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection{Less General}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\section{Specific}
\frame{\sectionpage}

\subsection{More Specific}
\frame{\subsectionpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can we also increase a bit the space between the section number and the section title?

Comment: @AlexG You're welcome! For changing the space, see l. 10 where I inserted the macro `\space`. Replace this with whatever space you like.

Comment: I tried with `\quad` which is wider than for subsections. Could you please point me to the file in the `beamer` package with the original definitions?

Comment: @AlexG It is in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`